# Python - Modify an input variable inside a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code:

```
def function(X):
    X.upper()
    if X == 'YES':
        print ('success')
    else:
        print ('fail')
function('yes')
```

Produces:

```
fail
```

But this code:

```
def function2(X):
    Y = X.upper()
    if Y == 'YES':
        print ('success')
    else:
        print ('fail')
function2('yes')
```

Gives me:

```
success
```

Why is this? I want to be able to edit my input variables within my functions. Is there a more efficient way to do this than copying variable values to new variables? I'm running Python 3.7.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Because `"".upper()` returns new string, it doesn't change the original. Strings are immutable in Python.